# How to scroll selectbox to specific option without changing selected value

Tags: jquery, scroll, drop-down-menu

I have a select drop down that is showing 10 of 100's of option elements. I've provided a search box and know the index of the option I want to scroll to the top of the select box. However, I do **NOT** want to change the selected value if an option has already been chosen.

All of the articles I've poured over here on deal with setting/resetting the selected value or calling `$('*theItem*').offset().top`. Unfortunately, I get a jscript error that `.top` is not a property.

This seems like it should be a simple thing, but suprisingly, it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scrollTop()` to scroll the selectbox.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/BFUyA/) with lots of rows. The height is 10 rows, the selected row is 40 and the scrollbar is at the 10th row.

Comment: Very interesting, and marked as answer, but how do you know that each value in the list is 16 "high"? I don't like using "magic" values.

Comment: A possible solution to this "magic value" problem: [1] Select the value to be scrolled, [2] Get the scroll position, [3] Change the value to the real value, [4] Set to the previous scroll position + height of the selectbox. Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/BFUyA/1/

Comment: Here is the updated and working version with a setTimeout hack added: http://jsfiddle.net/BFUyA/121/